# Post.js is not showing the blog post...Are there any errors here?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, sanity

There should be a block of blog post here but its empty:

[image]

Please check the map and the other syntaxes, I am not getting it.

```js
import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import sanityClient from "../client.js";
```

This is the export  default function below

```js
export default function Post(){ 
    const [postData, setPost] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        sanityClient
            .fetch(`*[_type =="post"]{
                title,
                slug,
                mainImage{
                    asset->{
                        _id;
                        url
                    },
                    alt
                }
             }`)
             .then((data) => setPost(data))
             .catch(console.error);
    },[]);
```

I think there is something missing in `postData` map.

```js
    return (
        <main className="bg-green-100 min-h-screen p-12">
            <section className="container mx-auto">
                <h1 className="text-5xl flex justify-center cursive">Blog Posts Page</h1>
                <h2 className="text-lg text-gray-600 flex justify-center mb-12">Welcome to my world!</h2>
                <div className="grid md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-8">
                    {postData && postData.map((post,index) => (
                        <article>
                            <Link to={"/post/" + post.slug.current} key={post.slug.current}>
                                <span className="block h-64 relative rounded shadow leading-snug bg-white border-l-8 border-green-400" key={index}>
                                  <img src={post.mainImage.asset.url} alt={post.mainImage.alt} className="w-full h-full rounded-r object-cover absolute" />
                                  <span className="block relative h-full flex justify-end items-end pr-4 pb-4">
                                    <h3 className="text-gray-800 text-lg font-blog px-3 py-4 bg-red-700 text-red-100 bg-opacity-75 rounded">{post.title}</h3>
                                  </span>
                                </span>
                            </Link>
                        </article>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>
    )    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out what is the result of your fetched data? Is your postData a definite array?

Comment: @LiSim nothing wrong there its preloaded from react dom